# How to convert this T-SQL query to be accepted by Access db?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I am trying to convert a query so it can be run on Access DB. For some reason access in the second part is throwing the exception

> Syntax error in query expression '(Select count(p.id) FROM post p..."

Here you can see that everything works perfectly on SQL Server 2008: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/388fc/1

```
SELECT
   c.id,
   c.CategoryName,
   c.Description,
   (SELECT count(t.id)
    FROM topic t
    WHERE t.categoryId = c.id) AS NumberOfTopics,
   (SELECT count(p.id)
    FROM post p
    JOIN topic t ON p.topicId = t.id
    WHERE t.categoryId = c.id) AS NumberOfPosts,
   (SELECT top 1 max(p.createdOn) 
    FROM post p
    JOIN topic t ON p.topicId = t.id
    WHERE t.categoryId = c.id) AS LastPostDate,
   (SELECT top 1 createdby 
    FROM post p
    JOIN topic t ON p.topicId = t.id
    WHERE t.categoryId = c.id 
    ORDER BY p.createdon DESC) AS byperson
FROM 
   category c;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access requires that you indicate the type of join: inner; left; or right.  It will not accept just `JOIN` as a synonym for `INNER JOIN`.

So make all of them `INNER JOIN` and see whether Access surfaces any other complaints.

Comment: Excellent, after I have changed that I've just changed the last part to (SELECT top 1 from P.CREATEDBY) and is working. Thank you!